# Android 11 - Notification media controls doesn't show on lock screen

Tags: android, android-notifications, samsung-mobile, android-11

Notification media controls doesn't show on lock screen for Samsung Devices S10/A20 with Android 11, but for other devices different than Samsung works well.

This code doesn't allow to show it on Lock Screen but if I remove it, works without any style:

```
   setStyle(
     MediaStyle()
       .setMediaSession(sessionToken)
       .setShowActionsInCompactView(*actionsToShow.toIntArray())
   )
```

I'm using NotificationCompat.Builder to create the notification.

I would like to know how can I fix that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My solution was to set the corresponding playback state on my media session:

```
mediaSession.setPlaybackState(
        PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 1f)
            .build()
    )
```

Same goes for `PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED`

Answer (score 0):

you just remove `.setMediaSession(sessionToken)`